# Layout Issue (floats/Padding)

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, padding

Am having layout issues, trying to understand floats and how to position elements. Am very new to css/html. Could someone help me understand how this layout is going to work. Some problems:

1) Unable to change the height of footer without ruining layout, footer seems to get pushed upwards.

2) When i inspect the page through chrome the footer div is included inside the  'wrapper' div when it's outside it in the code.

3) Adding padding to the content div also seems to break the layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>DCW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <!--NAV BAR -->

    <nav>
        <ul>
        <div class="float-left">
              <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">PD</a></li>
              <li><a href="news.asp">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="About.asp">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="Contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="float-right">
              <li><a href="#">Hire Us!</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <!-- HEADER -->

    <header>

        <div id="title_wrapper">

        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- BODY CONTENT -->

    <div id="wrapper">

       <div id="content">

           <div class="info">
             col1

           </div>

           <div class="info">
             col2

           </div>

        </div>

        <!-- SIDEBAR -->

        <div id="sidebar">

            <div id="sidebar-text">
                  content 2

            </div>

        </div>

      </div>

  <!-- FOOTER -->

   <footer>
     Footer

   </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

p.thick {
font-weight: bold;
}

h1, p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}



/*Nav */


nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
float: left;
}

nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
nav li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.float-left {
float:left;
}
.float-right {
float:right;
}


/* Header */

header #title_text{

 font-size: 100px;
 font-family: arial;

}

header #title_wrapper{
text-align:center;
position: relative;
top: 200px;

}

header {

background-color: orange;
position: relative;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
color:white;
margin:0;




}

/*Content*/

#wrapper{

min-height: 70%;
height: auto;
height: 70%;

}

#content{
float:left;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;

}


#sidebar{

float: left;
background-color: lightgrey;
height: 75%;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;

}

#sidebar-text{
font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-top: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 200%;
}



.img-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
}


.info{
width: 50%;
float: left;  
}


blockquote.style2 {
font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 50px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
outline-style: double;
outline-color: lightgrey;

}  

/* footer */
footer{
background-color: orange;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did make a +200px padding content with a +200px footer. Didn't changed anything besides the `display:inline-block` on the footer plus `box-sizing: border-box;` on the content.

```css
html, body
{
 width: 100%;   
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

p.thick {
font-weight: bold;
}

h1, p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}



/*Nav */


nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
float: left;
}

nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
nav li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.float-left {
float:left;
}
.float-right {
float:right;
}


/* Header */

header #title_text{

 font-size: 100px;
 font-family: arial;

}

header #title_wrapper{
text-align:center;
position: relative;
top: 200px;

}

header {

background-color: orange;
position: relative;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
color:white;
margin:0;




}

/*Content*/

#wrapper{

min-height: 70%;
height: auto;
height: 70%;

}

#content{
float:left;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding:100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


#sidebar{

float: left;
background-color: lightgrey;
height: 75%;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;

}

#sidebar-text{
font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-top: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 200%;
}



.img-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
}


.info{
width: 50%;
float: left;  
}


blockquote.style2 {
font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 50px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
outline-style: double;
outline-color: lightgrey;

}  

/* footer */
footer{
display: inline-block;
background-color: orange;
height:200px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>DCW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <!--NAV BAR -->

    <nav>
        <ul>
        <div class="float-left">
              <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">PD</a></li>
              <li><a href="news.asp">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="About.asp">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="Contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="float-right">
              <li><a href="#">Hire Us!</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <!-- HEADER -->

    <header>

        <div id="title_wrapper">

        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- BODY CONTENT -->

    <div id="wrapper">

       <div id="content">

           <div class="info">
             col1

           </div>

           <div class="info">
             col2

           </div>

        </div>

        <!-- SIDEBAR -->

        <div id="sidebar">

            <div id="sidebar-text">
                  content 2

            </div>

        </div>

      </div>

  <!-- FOOTER -->

   <footer>
     Footer

   </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: padding-bottom / top is okay. it seems to break when i add left or right padding

Comment: of course its width is 100%, if you add more to this you'll have an element bigger than the screen. except if you use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: updated now with box-sizing and padding in all directions; re-check please.

Comment: Thank you! time to do some research box sizing!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to give width and height as 100% for html and body or div in css  width is 100% by default. You can mention the width only when it is required.

for giving height to footer just add clear:both for footer selector

footer{background-color: orange;clear:both;height:50px;}

this will solve problems 1 & 2. When you add padding the design breaks because each time when you add width it keeps adding to the current width already given to the same div or element. This can be solved either by re adjusting the element width or using box-sizing: border-box.

Comment: tried this when i remove height 100% layout breaks - my content all gets pushed upwards